# Django: ¿Cómo puedo construir un formulario con multi select?

Tags: django, postgresql, html-select

Primero que nada decir que no quiero almacenar los choices separados por coma. Me gustaría que sea de la manera correcta, utilizando ManyToManyField en el models.py.

1. ¿Cómo funciona el ? cuando varios options son selected envía un array al servidor ? ¿Cómo puedo verificar esto en Django?

Quiero implementar un sistema de blog donde cada "Post" tendrá "tags", claramente esto es una relación Many to many. El usuario tiene una interfaz diferente al administrador de django donde él puede crear su Post, escribir el titulo, el texto y debería poder seleccionar los tags de una lista desplegable (ya sé que lo mejor es un input text pero no, **tiene que ser un select multiple**) y la próxima vez que intente editar el post le aparezcan seleccionados sus tags en ese mismo select multiple

2. ¿Cómo debería implementar el modelo (leí que debe ser usando un modelo intermedio), el form y el select del template?

Estoy usando Django 2, Postgres, Python3

Answer (score 0):

En este post de stackoverflow se detalla cómo implementar un select múltiple para una pregunta similar: [Django: How can I create a multiple select form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393134/django-how-can-i-create-a-multiple-select-form)

A continuación lo transcribo en castellano. En este caso, el campo es un multi select de países.

Emplearemos el tipo de campo "CheckboxSelectMultiple" como se describe a continuación.

En tu forms.py, escribe el siguiente código:

```
class CountryForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = (
        ("AUT", "Austria"),
        ("DEU", "Germany"),
        ("NLD", "Neitherlands"),
    )
    Countries = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                          choices=OPTIONS)
```

En la vista (views.py) define la siguiente función:

```
def countries_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CountryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            countries = form.cleaned_data.get('countries')
            # do something with your results
    else:
        form = CountryForm

    return render_to_response('render_country.html', {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

En la plantilla html incluye un fragmento similar a éste:

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: en que presentación se guarda en la base de datos? separados por coma o cómo?

Comment: Puedes guardarlo en tu modelo como tú prefieras. Recibirás un objeto del formulario con los valores seleccionados, y puedes tratarlo como mejor se ajuste a tu base de datos

Comment: Si te indico una forma específica de guardar el dato la respuesta no estará bien porque no hay una mejor o peor que cualquier otra. El multiselect es un elemento de front end y el dato se puede guardar como tú prefieras. Dicho esto, creo que los comentarios de este post de SO te pueden ser útiles

Comment: El post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407132/django-many-to-many-relationship-category